# vb.net can't get it to run script on button click

Tags: vb.net

I've created a button, but can't get it to run the msgbox("click") when I click.. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

```
Private Sub main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
With mybut
mybut.AutoSize = True
mybut.Name = "delete-btn" & btn_number
mybut.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(500, 20)
mybut.Text = "Delete"
End With
End Sub

Private Sub mybut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
MsgBox("Click")
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need mybut in the With. You can just type .PropName (e.g., .AutoSize = True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Handles` for your button click

```
Private Sub mybut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mybut.Click
MsgBox("Click")
End Sub
```

If it is a dynamic button you need to [add an event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
AddHandler mybut.Click, AddressOf Me.mybut_Click
```

Comment: Tried that but then I get an error on my handles saying that "Handles Clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types".. Don't even know what that means, I'm very new at this.

Comment: @user2989415 do you create the button dynamically or using the designer?

Comment: In that case you need to add event handlers for the button when you create it. I will update my answer to help

Comment: Ok, now I've tried to put the addhandler at different places in the script, but doesn't really seem to make a difference?

Comment: Add it just after you create the button, as it's dynamic you won't need the `Handles mybut.Click`